# unit test vb.net VS2012 failing when running all but working running them individually

Tags: vb.net, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, testing, unity-container

Hi all i work in a big project and when i try to run unit tests which are approx. 2100 unit tests, 1900 fails when trying to get the container "unity"

this is happening when clicking on run all, if i click to run one of the ones that are failing it works fine

this is the error:

An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for unity: The type name or alias Microsoft.Practices.Unity.InterceptionExtension.Configuration.InterceptionConfigurationExtension, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Interception.Configuration could not be resolved. Please check your configuration file and verify this type name.

and this is the line that is breaking:

ConfigurationManager.GetSection("unity")

Comment: Did you check your configuration file?

Comment: what should i check unity section is there and is declared.
right now i deleted the branch and performing a get operation

Comment: Please post your config file.

Comment: just done performing a get specific operation, wehre i got everything from the server overriding everithing i had, now they are working. thanks and regards